# MYSQL WHERE Clause Optimization

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a question
I have a primary key and key columns, 
is this optimized?

I have a query like this
    select col(s) where primary_key=val and key_part=val

and i want know if my query is optimized

if not how to optimize it.

I edited this.

Comment: Can you show the database structure ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much to optimize in the query itself. Using indexes over columns referenced in a where clause can improve performance though. Without knowing the details about your actual table and data, no further suggestions can be made.